# Show that $\mathbb{PR}^1$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

I know how to construct the charts.
I will have:
$$\phi_i(x_1,x_2) : U_i \to \mathbb{R}$$
where $Y_i \subset \mathbb{RP}^1$ defined by: $U_i :=\{(x_1,x_2) : x_i > 0\},$

$\phi_1(x_1,x_2) = \frac{x_2}{x_1},$ for example.

Let $S^1$ the unit circle with the stereographic projection:

$\mathcal{A} = \{(U_N,\phi_N), (U_S,\phi_S)\},$ defined as follows:

$$U_N := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\cap S^1\}$$ such that $ y \neq 1.$

$$U_S := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\cap S^1\}$$ such that $ y \neq -1.$

$$\phi_N(x,y) := \frac{x}{1-y},$$
$$\phi_S(x,y) := \frac{x}{1+y}.$$

How can I construct a diffeomorphism between these two manifolds using these charts? I don't know how to define it.. I don't know how to choose the functions defined on every open set and what open set to choose.

Thanks!

Comment: Another way to look at it: $\mathbb{P}^1\mathbb{R}=S^1_{+}/\sim$, identification being the points in the boundary of $S^1_{+}$. There is then a "natural" map from $\mathbb{P}^1 \mathbb{R}$ to $S^1$, which "stretches" to fill the circle.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo this not solves the problem. There is a natural homeomorphism, there is no result talking about diffeomorphism...

Comment: You now have a candidate for a diffeo. Just take local charts and analyze the local representation.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo, OK! Thanks